# Работа с REST API из PHP

Tags: php, rest, php-curl

Очень нужна помощь
Потребовалось обратиться из скрипта PHP к REST API гугла методом GET для получения инфы о производительности моего сайта.
Нагуглил утилиту curl и попытался ею это сделать.
Код выглядит так:

```js
<?php
$url = "https://google.com";
$url_desktop = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed";


  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 60;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if($result){
    echo ("заработало"); // чтобы понимать что провалился в IF
    $json=json_decode($result);
    print_r($result);
    echo("завершило"); // чтобы понимать что скрипт завершился
    }


?>
```

Когда делаю такое отбрашение через ajax в консоли браузера, спустя секунд 30-40 получаю в ответ здоровый объект полный данных.
Тут же, когда выполняю скрипт при помощи php my_script.php получаю в ответ веб-страницу:

```html
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="ru"><head><meta content="&#1055;&#1086;&#1080;&#1089;&#1082; &#1080;&#1085;&#1092;&#1086;&#1088;&#1084;&#1072;&#1094;&#1080;&#1080; &#1074; &#1080;&#1085;&#1090;&#1077;&#1088;&#1085;&#1077;&#1090;&#1077;: &#1074;&#1077;&#1073; &#1089;&#1090;&#1088;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1094;&#1099;, &#1082;&#1072;&#1088;&#1090;&#1080;&#1085;&#1082;&#1080;, &#1074;&#1080;&#1076;&#1077;&#1086; &#1080; &#1084;&#1085;&#1086;&#1075;&#1086;&#1077; &#1076;&#1088;&#1091;&#1075;&#1086;&#1077;." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script nonce="Yrm1C24yaI4VSmzk4Nkb3Q">(function(){window.google={kEI:'L8eYY7nRNfGQrgTxj6XYBg',kEXPI:'0,1359409,1709,4350,206,4804,2316,383,246,5,1129120,1197694,197,499,380101,16114,28684,22431,1361,12314,4750,12835,4998,13228,3847,10622,22741,5081,889,704,1279,2742,149,1103,840,2197,4100,3514,606,2023,2297,14670,3229,2843,7,29075,4695,1851,2614,13142,3,346,230,6459,149,13975,4,1528,2304,7039,27731,4163,3194,11442,2216,4437,16786,5824,2533,4097,4049,3,3541,1,42157,2,14019,25739,5679,1020,2379,28743,4568,6259,23418,1246,5841,14968,4332,7484,445,2,2,1,26632,8155,7381,15969,873,7830,11804,7,1922,5784,3995,12414,6716,1510,10682,4832,26504,15604,4532,14,82,3890,751,3010,10375,1501,679,1342,280,1779,2207,1644,1125,1746,6302,719,70,72,80,247,1960,1284,2411,1742,813,1224,10,308,551,1767,82,854,565,7,561,988,2095,377,63,399,96,426,938,96,42,291,2669,723,925,1431,3,261,524,2,216,23,79,2008,304,135,901,62,341,246,930,1,861,171,430,777,947,588,269,319,504,162,782,1897,16,63,3,442,96,599,552,917,348,83,67,700,580,1083,168,1086,5,342,1177,130,108,139,323,303,160,100,92,11,78,354,14,174,33,2,304,317,452,438,321,126,99,242,501,42,1,135,389,59,952,672,440,263,5,3,777,797,555,236,24,111,4,97,37,136,290,36,12,105,21,123,296,799,401,1,24,2,80,157,890,38,357,95,1175,527,57,516,261,1253,960,1368,329,2,342,30,135,47,1773,5275098,4069,158,173,8798849,3311,141,795,19735,1,1,346,2759,41,395,10,1,2,151,6,1,5,1,4,3,2,1,3,2,2,2,2,1,5,1,2,3,1,3,154,1,7,14,11,6,3,23946879,512,19,4041612,1964,16673,3405,5595,11,3835,5850,504857,976169',kBL:'oABN'};google.sn='webhp';google.kHL='ru';})();(function(){
var f=this||self;var h,k=[];function l(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||h}function m(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b}
function n(a,b,c,d,g){var e="";c||-1!==b.search("&ei=")||(e="&ei="+l(d),-1===b.search("&lei=")&&(d=m(d))&&(e+="&lei="+d));d="";!c&&f._cshid&&-1===b.search("&cshid=")&&"slh"!==a&&(d="&cshid="+f._cshid);c=c||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+e+"&zx="+Date.now()+d;/^http:/i.test(c)&&"https:"===window.location.protocol&&(google.ml&&google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:c,glmm:1}),c="");return c};h=google.kEI;google.getEI=l;google.getLEI=m;google.ml=function(){return null};google.log=function(a,b,c,d,g){if(c=n(a,b,c,d,g)){a=new Image;var e=k.length;k[e]=a;a.onerror=a.onload=a.onabort=function(){delete k[e]};a.src=c}};google.logUrl=n;}).call(this);(function(){google.y={};google.sy=[];google.x=function(a,b){if(a)var c=a.id;else{do c=Math.random();while(google.y[c])}google.y[c]=[a,b];return!1};google.sx=function(a){google.sy.push(a)};google.lm=[];google.plm=function(a){google.lm.push.apply(google.lm,a)};google.lq=[];google.load=function(a,b,c){google.lq.push([[a],b,c])};google.loadAll=function(a,b){google.lq.push([a,b])};google.bx=!1;google.lx=function(){};}).call(this);google.f={};(function(){
document.documentElement.addEventListener("submit",function(b){var a;if(a=b.target){var c=a.getAttribute("data-submitfalse");a="1"===c||"q"===c&&!a.elements.q.value?!0:!1}else a=!1;a&&(b.preventDefault(),b.stopPropagation())},!0);document.documentElement.addEventListener("click",function(b){var a;a:{for(a=b.target;a&&a!==document.documentElement;a=a.parentElement)if("A"===a.tagName){a="1"===a.getAttribute("data-nohref");break a}a=!1}a&&b.preventDefault()},!0);}).call(this);</script><style>#gb{font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif;height:30px}#gbz,#gbg{position:absolute;white-space:nowrap;top:0;height:30px;z-index:1000}#gbz{left:0;padding-left:4px}#gbg{right:0;padding-right:5px}#gbs{background:transparent;position:absolute;top:-999px;visibility:hidden;z-index:998;right:0}.gbto #gbs{background:#fff}#gbx3,#gbx4{background-color:#2d2d2d;background-image:none;_background-image:none;background-position:0 -138px;background-repeat:repeat-x;border-bottom:1px solid #000;font-size:24px;height:29px;_height:30px;opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;z-index:990}#gbx3{left:0}#gbx4{right:0}#gbb{position:relative}#gbbw{left:0;position:absolute;top:30px;width:100%}.gbtcb{position:absolute;visibility:hidden}#gbz .gbtcb{right:0}#gbg .gbtcb{left:0}.gbxx{display:none !important}.gbxo{opacity:0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=0) !important}.gbm{position:absolute;z-index:999;top:-999px;visibility:hidden;text-align:left;border:1px solid #bebebe;background:#fff;-moz-box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbrtl .gbm{-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbto .gbm,.gbto #gbs{top:29px;visibility:visible}#gbz .gbm{left:0}#gbg .gbm{right:0}.gbxms{background-color:#ccc;display:block;position:absolute;z-index:1;top:-1px;left:-2px;right:-2px;bottom:-2px;opacity:.4;-moz-border-radius:3px;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5);*opacity:1;*top:-2px;*left:-5px;*right:5px;*bottom:4px;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5)";opacity:1\0/;top:-4px\0/;left:-6px\0/;right:5px\0/;bottom:4px\0/}.gbma{position:relative;top:-1px;border-style:solid dashed dashed;border-color:transparent;border-top-color:#c0c0c0;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;font-size:0;height:0;line-height:0;width:0;border-width:3px 3px 0;padding-top:1px;left:4px}#gbztms1,#gbi4m1,#gbi4s,#gbi4t{zoom:1}.gbtc,.gbmc,.gbmcc{display:block;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}.gbmc{background:#fff;padding:10px 0;position:relative;z-index:2;zoom:1}.gbt{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block;line-height:27px;padding:0;vertical-align:top}.gbt{*display:inline}.gbto{box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-moz-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.gbzt,.gbgt{cursor:pointer;display:block;text-decoration:none !important}span#gbg6,span#gbg4{cursor:default}.gbts{border-left:1px solid transparent;border-right:1px solid transparent;display:block;*display:inline-block;padding:0 5px;position:relative;z-index:1000}.gbts{*display:inline}.gbzt .gbts{display:inline;zoom:1}.gbto .gbts{background:#fff;border-color:#bebebe;color:#36c;padding-bottom:1px;padding-top:2px}.gbz0l .gbts{color:#fff;font-weight:bold}.gbtsa{padding-right:9px}#gbz .gbzt,#gbz .gbgt,#gbg .gbgt{color:#ccc!important}.gbtb2{display:block;border-top:2px solid transparent}.gbto .gbzt .gbtb2,.gbto .gbgt .gbtb2{border-top-width:0}.gbtb .gbts{background:url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_8d5afc09.png);_background:url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b8_3615d64d.png);background-position:-27px -22px;border:0;font-size:0;padding:29px 0 0;*padding:27px 0 0;width:1px}.gbzt:hover,.gbzt:focus,.gbgt-hvr,.gbgt:focus{background-color:#4c4c4c;background-image:none;_background-image:none;background-position:0 -102px;background-repeat:repeat-x;outline:none;text-decoration:none !important}.gbpdjs .gbto .gbm{min-width:99%}.gbz0l .gbtb2{border-top-color:#dd4b39!important}#gbi4s,#gbi4s1{font-weight:bold}#gbg6.gbgt-hvr,#gbg6.gbgt:focus{background-color:transparent;background-image:none}.gbg4a{font-size:0;line-height:0}.gbg4a .gbts{padding:27px 5px 0;*padding:25px 5px 0}.gbto .gbg4a .gbts{padding:29px 5px 1px;*padding:27px 5px 1px}#gbi4i,#gbi4id{left:5px;border:0;height:24px;position:absolute;top:1px;width:24px}.gbto #gbi4i,.gbto #gbi4id{top:3px}.gbi4p{display:block;width:24px}#gbi4id{background-position:-44px -101px}#gbmpid{background-position:0 0}#gbmpi,#gbmpid{border:none;display:inline-block;height:48px;width:48px}#gbmpiw{display:inline-block;line-height:9px;padding-left:20px;margin-top:10px;position:relative}#gbmpi,#gbmpid,#gbmpiw{*display:inline}#gbg5{font-size:0}#gbgs5{padding:5px !important}.gbto #gbgs5{padding:7px 5px 6px !important}#gbi5{background:url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_8d5afc09.png);_background:url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b8_3615d64d.png);background-position:0 0;display:block;font-size:0;height:17px;width:16px}.gbto #gbi5{background-position:-6px -22px}.gbn .gbmt,.gbn .gbmt:visited,.gbnd .gbmt,.gbnd .gbmt:visited{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gbmt,.gbf .gbmt:visited{color:#900 !important}.gbmt,.gbml1,.gbmlb,.gbmt:visited,.gbml1:visited,.gbmlb:visited{color:#36c !important;text-decoration:none !important}.gbmt,.gbmt:visited{display:block}.gbml1,.gbmlb,.gbml1:visited,.gbmlb:visited{display:inline-block;margin:0 10px}.gbml1,.gbmlb,.gbml1:visited,.gbmlb:visited{*display:inline}.gbml1,.gbml1:visited{padding:0 10px}.gbml1-hvr,.gbml1:focus{outline:none;text-decoration:underline !important}#gbpm .gbml1{display:inline;margin:0;padding:0;white-space:nowrap}.gbmlb,.gbmlb:visited{line-height:27px}.gbmlb-hvr,.gbmlb:focus{outline:none;text-decoration:underline !important}.gbmlbw{color:#ccc;margin:0 10px}.gbmt{padding:0 20px}.gbmt:hover,.gbmt:focus{background:#eee;cursor:pointer;outline:0 solid black;text-decoration:none !important}.gbm0l,.gbm0l:visited{color:#000 !important;font-weight:bold}.gbmh{border-top:1px solid #bebebe;font-size:0;margin:10px 0}#gbd4 .gbmc{background:#f5f5f5;padding-top:0}#gbd4 .gbsbic::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical{background-color:#f5f5f5;margin-top:2px}#gbmpdv{background:#fff;border-bottom:1px solid #bebebe;-moz-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.12);-o-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.12);-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.12);box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.12);position:relative;z-index:1}#gbd4 .gbmh{margin:0}.gbmtc{padding:0;margin:0;line-height:27px}.GBMCC:last-child:after,#GBMPAL:last-child:after{content:'\0A\0A';white-space:pre;position:absolute}#gbmps{*zoom:1}#gbd4 .gbpc,#gbmpas .gbmt{line-height:17px}#gbd4 .gbpgs .gbmtc{line-height:27px}#gbd4 .gbmtc{border-bottom:1px solid #bebebe}#gbd4 .gbpc{display:inline-block;margin:16px 0 10px;padding-right:50px;vertical-align:top}#gbd4 .gbpc{*display:inline}.gbpc .gbps,.gbpc .gbps2{display:block;margin:0 20px}#gbmplp.gbps{margin:0 10px}.gbpc .gbps{color:#000;font-weight:bold}.gbpc .gbpd{margin-bottom:5px}.gbpd .gbmt,.gbpd .gbps{color:#666 !important}.gbpd .gbmt{opacity:.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)}.gbps2{color:#666;display:block}.gbp0{display:none}.gbp0 .gbps2{font-weight:bold}#gbd4 .gbmcc{margin-top:5px}.gbpmc{background:#fef9db}.gbpmc .gbpmtc{padding:10px 20px}#gbpm{border:0;*border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0;white-space:normal}#gbpm .gbpmtc{border-top:none;color:#000 !important;font:11px Arial,sans-serif}#gbpms{*white-space:nowrap}.gbpms2{font-weight:bold;white-space:nowrap}#gbmpal{*border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border:0;margin:0;white-space:nowrap;width:100%}.gbmpala,.gbmpalb{font:13px Arial,sans-serif;line-height:27px;padding:10px 20px 0;white-space:nowrap}.gbmpala{padding-left:0;text-align:left}.gbmpalb{padding-right:0;text-align:right}#gbmpasb .gbps{color:#000}#gbmpal .gbqfbb{margin:0 20px}.gbp0 .gbps{*display:inline}a.gbiba{margin:8px 20px 10px}.gbmpiaw{display:inline-block;padding-right:10px;margin-bottom:6px;margin-top:10px}.gbxv{visibility:hidden}.gbmpiaa{display:block;margin-top:10px}.gbmpia{border:none;display:block;height:48px;width:48px}.gbmpnw{display:inline-block;height:auto;margin:10px 0;vertical-align:top}
.gbqfb,.gbqfba,.gbqfbb{-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;cursor:default !important;display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;height:29px;line-height:29px;min-width:54px;*min-width:70px;padding:0 8px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none !important;-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none}.gbqfb:focus,.gbqfba:focus,.gbqfbb:focus{border:1px solid #4d90fe;-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);outline:none}.gbqfb-hvr:focus,.gbqfba-hvr:focus,.gbqfbb-hvr:focus{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #fff,0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #fff,0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #fff,0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}.gbqfb-no-focus:focus{border:1px solid #3079ed;-moz-box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none}.gbqfb-hvr,.gbqfba-hvr,.gbqfbb-hvr{-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}.gbqfb::-moz-focus-inner,.gbqfba::-moz-focus-inner,.gbqfbb::-moz-focus-inner{border:0}.gbqfba,.gbqfbb{border:1px solid #dcdcdc;border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);color:#444 !important;font-size:11px}.gbqfb{background-color:#4d90fe;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4d90fe),to(#4787ed));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#4d90fe',EndColorStr='#4787ed');border:1px solid #3079ed;color:#fff!important;margin:0 0}.gbqfb-hvr{border-color:#2f5bb7}.gbqfb-hvr:focus{border-color:#2f5bb7}.gbqfb-hvr,.gbqfb-hvr:focus{background-color:#357ae8;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4d90fe),to(#357ae8));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8)}.gbqfb:active{background-color:inherit;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)}.gbqfba{background-color:#f5f5f5;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#f5f5f5),to(#f1f1f1));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#f5f5f5',EndColorStr='#f1f1f1')}.gbqfba-hvr,.gbqfba-hvr:active{background-color:#f8f8f8;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#f8f8f8),to(#f1f1f1));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#f1f1f1);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#f8f8f8',EndColorStr='#f1f1f1')}.gbqfbb{background-color:#fff;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#fff),to(#fbfbfb));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#fbfbfb);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#fbfbfb);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#fbfbfb);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#fbfbfb);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#fff,#fbfbfb);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff',EndColorStr='#fbfbfb')}.gbqfbb-hvr,.gbqfbb-hvr:active{background-color:#fff;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#fff),to(#f8f8f8));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#f8f8f8);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#f8f8f8);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#f8f8f8);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#f8f8f8);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#fff,#f8f8f8);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff',EndColorStr='#f8f8f8')}.gbqfba-hvr,.gbqfba-hvr:active,.gbqfbb-hvr,.gbqfbb-hvr:active{border-color:#c6c6c6;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);color:#222 !important}.gbqfba:active,.gbqfbb:active{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}
#gbmpas{max-height:220px}#gbmm{max-height:530px}.gbsb{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;display:block;position:relative;*zoom:1}.gbsbic{overflow:auto}.gbsbis .gbsbt,.gbsbis .gbsbb{-webkit-mask-box-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,color-stop(0,rgba(0,0,0,.1)),color-stop(.5,rgba(0,0,0,.8)),color-stop(1,rgba(0,0,0,.1)));left:0;margin-right:0;opacity:0;position:absolute;width:100%}.gbsb .gbsbt:after,.gbsb .gbsbb:after{content:"";display:block;height:0;left:0;position:absolute;width:100%}.gbsbis .gbsbt{background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(0,0,0,.2)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.2),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.2),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.2),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.2),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,.2),rgba(0,0,0,0));height:6px;top:0}.gbsb .gbsbt:after{border-top:1px solid #ebebeb;border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);top:0}.gbsb .gbsbb{-webkit-mask-box-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,color-stop(0,rgba(0,0,0,.1)),color-stop(.5,rgba(0,0,0,.8)),color-stop(1,rgba(0,0,0,.1)));background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.2)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.2),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.2),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.2),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:-o-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.2),rgba(0,0,0,0));background-image:linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,.2),rgba(0,0,0,0));bottom:0;height:4px}.gbsb .gbsbb:after{border-bottom:1px solid #ebebeb;border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);bottom:0}
</style><style>body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#1558d6}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}body{background:#fff;color:#000}a{color:#4b11a8;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#1558d6}a:visited{color:#4b11a8}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#f8f9fa;border:solid 1px;border-color:#dadce0 #70757a #70757a #dadce0;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}#WqQANb a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#dadce0}.lst:focus{outline:none}.Ucigb{width:458px}</style><script nonce="Yrm1C24yaI4VSmzk4Nkb3Q">(function(){window.google.erd={jsr:1,bv:1700,de:true};
var h=this||self;var k,l=null!=(k=h.mei)?k:1,n,p=null!=(n=h.sdo)?n:!0,q=0,r,t=google.erd,v=t.jsr;google.ml=function(a,b,d,m,e){e=void 0===e?2:e;b&&(r=a&&a.message);if(google.dl)return google.dl(a,e,d),null;if(0>v){window.console&&console.error(a,d);if(-2===v)throw a;b=!1}else b=!a||!a.message||"Error loading script"===a.message||q>=l&&!m?!1:!0;if(!b)return null;q++;d=d||{};b=encodeURIComponent;var c="/gen_204?atyp=i&ei="+b(google.kEI);google.kEXPI&&(c+="&jexpid="+b(google.kEXPI));c+="&srcpg="+b(google.sn)+"&jsr="+b(t.jsr)+"&bver="+b(t.bv);var f=a.lineNumber;void 0!==f&&(c+="&line="+f);var g=
a.fileName;g&&(0<g.indexOf("-extension:/")&&(e=3),c+="&script="+b(g),f&&g===window.location.href&&(f=document.documentElement.outerHTML.split("\n")[f],c+="&cad="+b(f?f.substring(0,300):"No script found.")));c+="&jsel="+e;for(var u in d)c+="&",c+=b(u),c+="=",c+=b(d[u]);c=c+"&emsg="+b(a.name+": "+a.message);c=c+"&jsst="+b(a.stack||"N/A");12288<=c.length&&(c=c.substr(0,12288));a=c;m||google.log(0,"",a);return a};window.onerror=function(a,b,d,m,e){r!==a&&(a=e instanceof Error?e:Error(a),void 0===d||"lineNumber"in a||(a.lineNumber=d),void 0===b||"fileName"in a||(a.fileName=b),google.ml(a,!1,void 0,!1,"SyntaxError"===a.name||"SyntaxError"===a.message.substring(0,11)||-1!==a.message.indexOf("Script error")?3:0));r=null;p&&q>=l&&(window.onerror=null)};})();(function(){try{/*

 Copyright The Closure Library Authors.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
var e=this||self;var aa=function(a,b,c,d){d=d||{};d._sn=["cfg",b,c].join(".");window.gbar.logger.ml(a,d)};var g=window.gbar=window.gbar||{},h=window.gbar.i=window.gbar.i||{},ba;function _tvn(a,b){a=parseInt(a,10);return isNaN(a)?b:a}function _tvf(a,b){a=parseFloat(a);return isNaN(a)?b:a}function _tvv(a){return!!a}function p(a,b,c){(c||g)[a]=b}g.bv={n:_tvn("2",0),r:"",f:".66.",e:"",m:_tvn("1",1)};
function ca(a,b,c){var d="on"+b;if(a.addEventListener)a.addEventListener(b,c,!1);else if(a.attachEvent)a.attachEvent(d,c);else{var f=a[d];a[d]=function(){var k=f.apply(this,arguments),l=c.apply(this,arguments);return void 0==k?l:void 0==l?k:l&&k}}}var da=function(a){return function(){return g.bv.m==a}},ea=da(1),fa=da(2);p("sb",ea);p("kn",fa);h.a=_tvv;h.b=_tvf;h.c=_tvn;h.i=aa;var r=window.gbar.i.i;var t=function(){},u=function(){},ja=function(a){var b=new Image,c=ha;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){try{delete ia[c]}catch(d){}};ia[c]=b;b.src=a;ha=c+1},ia=[],ha=0;p("logger",{il:u,ml:t,log:ja});var v=window.gbar.logger;var w={},ka={},x=[],la=h.b("0.1",.1),ma=h.a("1",!0),na=function(a,b){x.push([a,b])},oa=function(a,b){w[a]=b},pa=function(a){return a in w},A={},B=function(a,b){A[a]||(A[a]=[]);A[a].push(b)},C=function(a){B("m",a)},qa=function(a,b){var c=document.createElement("script");c.src=a;c.async=ma;Math.random()<la&&(c.onerror=function(){c.onerror=null;t(Error("Bundle load failed: name="+(b||"UNK")+" url="+a))});(document.getElementById("xjsc")||document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]||
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]).appendChild(c)},sa=function(a){for(var b,c=0;(b=x[c])&&b[0]!=a;++c);!b||b[1].l||b[1].s||(b[1].s=!0,ra(2,a),b[1].url&&qa(b[1].url,a),b[1].libs&&D&&D(b[1].libs))},ta=function(a){B("gc",a)},ua=null,va=function(a){ua=a},ra=function(a,b,c){if(ua){a={t:a,b:b};if(c)for(var d in c)a[d]=c[d];try{ua(a)}catch(f){}}};p("mdc",w);p("mdi",ka);p("bnc",x);p("qGC",ta);p("qm",C);p("qd",A);p("lb",sa);p("mcf",oa);p("bcf",na);p("aq",B);p("mdd","");
p("has",pa);p("trh",va);p("tev",ra);if(h.a("m;/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.WEPncdil2Uw.O/d=1/rs=AHpOoo-eOecLLtOXEl3I3kIuMsKXRkDMmA/m=__features__")){var E=function(a,b){return wa?a||b:b},xa=h.a("1"),ya=h.a(""),za=h.a(""),wa=h.a(""),Aa=window.gapi=E(window.gapi,{}),Ba=function(a,b){var c=function(){g.dgl(a,b)};xa?C(c):(B("gl",c),sa("gl"))},Ca={},Da=function(a){a=a.split(":");for(var b;(b=a.pop())&&Ca[b];);return!b},D=function(a){function b(){for(var c=a.split(":"),d,f=0;d=c[f];++f)Ca[d]=1;for(c=0;d=x[c];++c)d=d[1],(f=d.libs)&&!d.l&&d.i&&
Da(f)&&d.i()}g.dgl(a,b)},G=window.___jsl=E(window.___jsl,{});G.h=E(G.h,"m;/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.WEPncdil2Uw.O/d=1/rs=AHpOoo-eOecLLtOXEl3I3kIuMsKXRkDMmA/m=__features__");G.ms=E(G.ms,"https://apis.google.com");G.m=E(G.m,"");G.l=E(G.l,[]);G.dpo=E(G.dpo,"");xa||x.push(["gl",{url:"//ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/abc/glm_e7bb39a7e1a24581ff4f8d199678b1b9.js"}]);var Ea={pu:ya,sh:"",si:za,hl:"ru"};w.gl=Ea;wa?Aa.load||p("load",Ba,Aa):p("load",Ba,Aa);p("dgl",Ba);p("agl",Da);h.o=xa};var Fa=h.b("0.1",.001),Ga=0;
function _mlToken(a,b){try{if(1>Ga){Ga++;var c=a;b=b||{};var d=encodeURIComponent,f=["//www.google.com/gen_204?atyp=i&zx=",(new Date).getTime(),"&jexpid=",d("28834"),"&srcpg=",d("prop=1"),"&jsr=",Math.round(1/Fa),"&ogev=",d("L8eYY9XSNpfRqwHozY-QCQ"),"&ogf=",g.bv.f,"&ogrp=",d(""),"&ogv=",d("494472211.0"),"&oggv="+d("es_plusone_gc_20221206.0_p0"),"&ogd=",d("com"),"&ogc=",d("RUS"),"&ogl=",d("ru")];b._sn&&(b._sn=
"og."+b._sn);for(var k in b)f.push("&"),f.push(d(k)),f.push("="),f.push(d(b[k]));f.push("&emsg=");f.push(d(c.name+":"+c.message));var l=f.join("");Ha(l)&&(l=l.substr(0,2E3));var n=l;var m=window.gbar.logger._aem(a,n);ja(m)}}catch(q){}}var Ha=function(a){return 2E3<=a.length},Ia=function(a,b){return b};function Ja(a){t=a;p("_itl",Ha,v);p("_aem",Ia,v);p("ml",t,v);a={};w.er=a}h.a("")?Ja(function(a){throw a;}):h.a("1")&&Math.random()<Fa&&Ja(_mlToken);var _E="left",Ka=h.a(""),La=h.a(""),I=function(a,b){var c=a.className;H(a,b)||(a.className+=(""!=c?" ":"")+b)},J=function(a,b){var c=a.className;b=new RegExp("\\s?\\b"+b+"\\b");c&&c.match(b)&&(a.className=c.replace(b,""))},H=function(a,b){b=new RegExp("\\b"+b+"\\b");a=a.className;return!(!a||!a.match(b))},Ma=function(a,b){H(a,b)?J(a,b):I(a,b)},Na=function(a,b){a[b]=function(c){var d=arguments;g.qm(function(){a[b].apply(this,d)})}},Oa=function(a){a=
[La?"":"https://www.gstatic.com","/og/_/js/d=1/k=","og.og2.en_US.0s3bFmfZPfU.es5.O","/rt=j/m=",a,"/rs=","AA2YrTtfIKGifpK5YZVkSkApV7iJIi0MXA"];Ka&&a.push("?host=www.gstatic.com&bust=og.og2.en_US.0E62e8XpPSI.es5.DU");a=a.join("");qa(a)};p("ca",I);p("cr",J);p("cc",H);h.k=I;h.l=J;h.m=H;h.n=Ma;h.p=Oa;h.q=Na;var Pa=["gb_71","gb_155"],Qa;function Ra(a){Qa=a}function Sa(a){var b=Qa&&!a.href.match(/.*\/accounts\/ClearSID[?]/)&&encodeURIComponent(Qa());b&&(a.href=a.href.replace(/([?&]continue=)[^&]*/,"$1"+b))}function Ta(a){window.gApplication&&(a.href=window.gApplication.getTabUrl(a.href))}function Ua(a){try{var b=(document.forms[0].q||"").value;b&&(a.href=a.href.replace(/([?&])q=[^&]*|$/,function(c,d){return(d||"&")+"q="+encodeURIComponent(b)}))}catch(c){r(c,"sb","pq")}}
var Va=function(){for(var a=[],b,c=0;b=Pa[c];++c)(b=document.getElementById(b))&&a.push(b);return a},Wa=function(){var a=Va();return ... ... </body></html>
```

Совершенно не пойму как подступиться к вопросу, помогите, пожалуйста, получить и вывести объект с сервера при помощи php.

Comment: Вы через curl забираете содержимое сайта https://google.com, что и видно в вашем коде и в том, что получаете в ответ.

Comment: А вот как мне забирать овтет на GET-запрос вместо содержимого сайта?)
Что у меня получилось я и так понимаю, не понимаю как сделать правильно

Comment: Очевидно, вам надо указать имя того URL, который вам необходим. Сейчас у вас в php-скрипте используется curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);, где $url = "https://google.com";

Comment: Понял, перепутал $url и $url_desktop 
Спасибо)